Flutterflow: Determining a User's Supabase Authentication Method
In my Flutterflow project I'm allowing users to authenticate w/ email or Apple Sign-In through Supabase but I'd like to hide a "Change Password" button for users who signed in with Apple since they don't really have a password.
What's the easiest way to accomplish this? I don't see an "out of the box" way in Flutterflow to determine a user's Supabase authentication method!

In case it helps someone else, I solved this by inserting/updating an auth_method field in my user metadata table with a value that gets set depending on which auth button was tapped ("apple", "email" etc.). (Not using supabase's auth table.)
